# How to set colspan and rowspan in JSF panelGrid?

Tags: jsf, html-table, panelgrid

How can I set `colspan` and `rowspan` in JSF `<h:panelGrid>`?

Answer (score 63):

None of both is possible with the standard JSF implementation. There are 3 ways to fix this:

1. Write plain HTML yourself. A `<h:panelGrid>` basically renders a HTML `<table>`. Do the same.
2. Create a custom HTML renderer which supports this. It'll however be a lot of sweat and pain.
3. Use a 3rd party component library which supports this.

   - [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) has a [`<t:panelGroup>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_panelGroup.html) component which supports `colspan` in `<h:panelGrid>`.
   - [RichFaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/) (3.x only) has a [`<rich:column>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_column.html) component which supports both `colspan` and `rowspan` in [`<rich:dataTable>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dataTable.html).
   - [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) has a `<p:row>` next to `<p:column>` which is supported in both [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) and [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml) (also with `<p:columnGroup>`).

Comment: Have you tried the rich:column in a panelgrid with colspan? Because the doc says: "The "colspan", "rowspan", and "breakbefore" attributes only affect columns in a <rich:dataTable>, not those in a <rich:extendedDataTable>."

Answer (score 9):

Since 24 januari 2012 Primefaces also has the possibility to use colspan and rowspan in the panelGrid component of Primefaces. See:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml

Answer (score 2):

Assume

1. a message resource file with two entries:

   > key.row=**`</td></tr><tr><td`**
   >  key.gt=**`>`**
2. row.xhtml

   ```
   <ui:composition 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" >

       <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{colspan-2}">
           <h:panelGroup />
       </c:forEach>

       <h:panelGroup>
         <h:outputText value="#{i18n['key.row']}" escape="false" />
         <h:outputText value=" colspan='#{colspan}' #{cellAttributes}" />
         <h:outputText value="#{i18n['key.gt']}" escape="false" />

         <ui:insert />
       </h:panelGroup>

   </ui:composition>
   ```

   then, for example

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
     <h:outputText value="r1-c1" />
     <h:outputText value="r1-c2" />
     <h:outputText value="r1-c3" />

     <ui:decorate template="/row.xhtml">
       <ui:param name="colspan" value="3" />
       <ui:param name="cellAttributes" value=" align='center'" />

       <div>Hello!!!!!</div>
     </ui:decorate>
   ```

Prints a table with 3 rows:

1. r1-c1, r1-c2 , r1-c3
2. 3 blank cells
3. a cell aligned center, having colspan 3 and containing a hello div.

Comment: Not the way i would do things either. Even though it might answer the question, please also try to educate. Bad practices are.. well.. bad. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use: rich:column `colspan="2"` of **RichFaces**

```
<rich:column colspan="2">                        
<h:outputText  value="Ingrese el texto de la imagen" /> 
</rich:column>
```

Comment: this question is about JSF and not richfaces

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BalusC's answer and want to add, that the Primefaces JSF2 component library also offers this functionality if you use its [p:dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml) component. It is called grouping there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define column span in panel grid but if used wisely you can make it happen by just plain  tag only. One example I would like to show you.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" >
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:commandButton image="resources/images/Regular5.jpg" action="booking/Create.jsf?faces-redirect=truebookingType=REGULAR">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton id="button2" image="resources/images/Casual2.jpg" action="booking/Create.jsf?faces-redirect=truebookingType=CASUAL">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:commandButton id="button3" image="resources/images/Instant2.jpg" action="booking/Create.jsf?faces-redirect=truebookingType=INSTANT">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton id="button4" image="resources/images/Outstation6.jpg" action="booking/Create.jsf?faces-redirect=truebookingType=OUTSTATION">
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton id="button5" image="resources/images/ShareMyCar.jpg" action="booking/Create.jsf?faces-redirect=truebookingType=OUTSTATION">
</h:commandButton>
```

Please note that button5 spans two columns given the size it requires.