# primefaces columns disappear on a panelgrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I dont know why but the columns I set on a panel grid get merged as if they  were only one column,

Here is the code

```
<h:panelGrid id="formOcurrencia">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="Número de catalogo:" for="numcatInput" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="numcatInput"
                    value="#{ocurrenciaDM.ocurrencia.catalogNumbOcurrencia}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="Número de record:" for="numrecInput" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="numrecInput"
                    value="#{ocurrenciaDM.ocurrencia.recordNumbOcurrencia}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="Fecha inicial:" for="cal_ocurr1Input" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:calendar id="cal_ocurr1Input"
                    value="#{ocurrenciaDM.ocurrencia.fechaInicialOcurrencia}"
                    mindate="1/1/1960" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" navigator="true"
                    display="inline">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="GMT+5" />
                </p:calendar>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="Fecha final:" for="cal_ocurr2Input" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:calendar id="cal_ocurr2Input"
                    value="#{ocurrenciaDM.ocurrencia.fechaFinalOcurrencia}"
                    mindate="1/1/1960" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" navigator="true"
                    display="inline">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="GMT+5" />
                </p:calendar>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And here it is how shows on the page

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label for="taxonomiaAdminForm:numcatInput">
Número de catalogo:</label><input aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="taxonomiaAdminForm:numcatInput" name="taxonomiaAdminForm:numcatInput" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text"><label for="taxonomiaAdminForm:numrecInput">
Número de record:</label><input aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="taxonomiaAdminForm:numrecInput" name="taxonomiaAdminForm:numrecInput" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr1Input">
Fecha inicial:</label><span id="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr1Input"><input aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr1Input_input" name="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr1Input_input" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all hasDatepicker" type="text"></span><label for="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr2Input">
Fecha final:</label><span id="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr2Input"><input aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr2Input_input" name="taxonomiaAdminForm:cal_ocurr2Input_input" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all hasDatepicker" type="text"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="taxonomiaAdminForm:cont_indInput">
Conteo individual:</label><input aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="taxonomiaAdminForm:cont_indInput" name="taxonomiaAdminForm:cont_indInput" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

There is only one column on each row, I copy pasted the example on the page and it work, then I copy some of the rows to my panelgrid and the columns get lost again.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting mixed up between the general jsf components and the primefaces components. In your example you are using `<h:panelGrid>`. If you change this to `<p:panelGrid>` it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all those `<p:row>` and `<p:column>` and set the number of columns in the `<h:panelGrid>`. Note that the `columns` attribute will automatically build the HTML table in order to have a `<table>` with four `<td>` elements per `<tr>` 9in HTML terms).

```
<h:panelGrid id="formOcurrencia" columns="4">
    <h:outputLabel value="Número de catalogo:" for="numcatInput" />
    <p:inputText id="numcatInput"
        value="#{ocurrenciaDM.ocurrencia.catalogNumbOcurrencia}" />
    <!-- and all the other components... -->
</h:panelGrid>
```

Another advice: your `<h:panelGrid>` id shouldn't be `formXxx` instead use a more meaningful name like `pnlXxx` and let the `form` prefix for `<h:form>` tag.

Since it looks you want to use colspan / rowspan, you should seek for the solution proposed here: [How to set colspan and rowspan in JSF panelGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3111081/1065197). Due that you're using PrimeFaces, you should use `<p:panelGrid>` instead.

Comment: I know, I had it set like that before, but I need colspan that is why I am using row and column

Comment: because I already had a panel grid I thought I just need to add row and columns, anyways it got fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know what the problem was, I started deleting all the columns and rows until I had one row and 2 columns I still had the same problem I used a panel grid with columns that worked, and started just copying each row to that part and testing, I added at first one column at the time and tested, and they worked. I still dont see the problem with my initial code, it is practically the same.