# One common column in a jsf datatable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I'm manipulating a dataTable in order to display a List of objects. 
In the first 4 columns it shows attributes related to the object such as año(year),etc.., as you can see in the image below.
The thing is.., in the 5th,I want to insert in a one simple column, an image that is common to all the objects in the table. 
Is there a way to to this with jsf ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF without xxxFaces: `<td rowspan="2">`
In RichFaces: `<rich:column rowspan="2">`
In PrimeFaces: `<p:column rowspan="2">`
(Change 2 to proper number)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Nevertheless, I was expecting use jsf labels such as h:column in a h:dataTable

Comment: `h:column` didn't support rowspan. See answers for similar question [how to give colspan and rowspan in JSF panelgrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111081/how-to-give-colspan-and-rowspan-in-jsf-panelgrid)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you will use custom table tag with ui:repeat you could achieve what your are trying to do.
e.g

```
<table>
<ui:repeat var=... value=... varStatus="myVarStatus">
<tr>
  <td>.</td>
  <td>..</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

you could use this construction "#{myVarStatus.index}"  to add proper collspan in right moment.

It is easy to do with richfaces rich:column tag.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Nevertheless, I was expecting use jsf labels such as h:column in a h:dataTable