# how to single h:panelgrid into apply colspan?

Tags: jsf

USe lib <%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
how to apply single panel grid in colspan?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111081/how-to-give-colspan-and-rowspan-in-jsf-panelgrid

Comment: yes i try but use diffrents panel grid then not proper table header and contents display so i need one panel grid in use colspan
For eg:
 table in five column and second column to need to one value so i need to give cols pan and first and third column in 5 value so

Comment: Why don't you write your own HTML table? You may enclose it within <h:panelGroup> afterwards if needed.